# Can you download an image with its URL using Firebase Functions?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

This is what the website says - (https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/extend-with-functions)

```
await bucket.file(filePath).download({destination: tempFilePath});
```

I wonder if the filepath can be a URL.

Comment: The documentation (https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/storage/latest/Bucket.html#file) doesn't seem to hint that this might be possible. To map a download URL to a file path, you might want to do so using the client-side Firebase SDK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible with the Cloud Storage SDK for nodejs.  It doesn't know anything about how download URLs work that are created in Firebase client apps.

If you are going to store some data about an image, I suggest storing both the URL and the path of the image in the bucket.  You can then use that path when you call `bucket.file()` if you need to work with it in Cloud Functions.